# Grail or Ruby on rails for an highly interactive event based web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grails, event-based-programming

With Java and Perl background, I have narrowed down the web framework choices to Grail or RoR.

The web application is a highly interactive content management app ran on private cloud.

One vision is to make all the widgets on the web pages to be event driven: click, double click, right click, keyboard shortcuts, etc.  Does either framework supports this?

Comment: on the web you are limited (somewhat) by the fact that you are looking at HTML. this means that things like double clicks and keyboard shortcuts are not recognized by HTML. solutions to this involve (usually) javascript and flash.

that has little to do with the framework you choose. the framework (RoR or Grails) controls how you generate content for your users, and the content (via javascript, flash, etc) controls how your users interact with your site.

Comment: That type of stuff is supported pretty easily in Lift (Scala, another JVM language). But RoR has rjs which might do what you need. I've never used Grails so I couldn't tell you what's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have developed with groovy on grails and ruby on rails. You can do highly interactive AJAX work with either of those frameworks - it won't matter which.

Scaling the application has more to do with caching, fronting the application with a high-speed web server for static content and that kind of thing.

When it comes to making a straight choice between grails and rails I'd consider two things:

- which of grails and rails are you most familiar with?
- do you have any legacy Java or Ruby code you need to integrate with?

Apart from those two considerations, there isn't much to choose between them.

Answer (score 0):

Both Grails and Rails will be able to provide the backend support for what you are looking to achieve. Frontend matters such as click and double click will require you to weigh up client side technologies such as Javascript, Flash, Silverlight etc.